# Custom SignIn form buttons are not responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, aws-amplify

Using a custom Signin form in aws-amplify causes all buttons not to respond to clicks. State does not change to Signedup or other 'forgot password'

I am working on customizing the SignIn form for **aws-amplify**. The custom SignIn form comes up when I start my application but all buttons don't respond to clicks. State also does not change when clicking on <kbd>Signup</kbd> or <kbd>Forgot password</kbd>. I am following the following articles on how to do this:

[How to Easily Customize The AWS Amplify Authentication UI](https://blog.kylegalbraith.com/2018/11/29/how-to-easily-customize-the-aws-amplify-authentication-ui/)

[Customize withAuthenticator](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#customize-withauthenticator)

Below are snippets from my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import .. from 'react-native';

import {SignIn} from 'aws-amplify-react-native';

export default class SignInScreen extends SignIn {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._validAuthStates = ["signIn", "signedOut", "signedUp"];
  }
  showComponent(theme) {
    return (
    ...
        <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}
                            onClick={() => {super.signIn(); Alert.alert('Alert',"I clicked login")}}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonContainer} onClick={() => super.changeState("forgotPassword")}>
            <Text style={styles.signupText}>Forgot your password?</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonContainer} onClick={() => super.changeState("signUp")}>
            <Text style={styles.signupText}>Sign up</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Below is how I enable Auth for my app in **App.js**:

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, false, [
    <SignInScreen/>,
    <ConfirmSignIn/>,
    <VerifyContact/>,
    <SignUp/>,
    <ConfirmSignUp/>,
    <ForgotPassword/>,
    <RequireNewPassword />
])
```

The custom SignIn form renders correctly. I can type in my username and password but clicking on any button, does nothing.

Any hints, suggestions on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. For anybody who might see this issue, for TouchableHighlight: use onPress instead of onClick. Although react-native does not complain, it does not work.

instead of

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonContainer} onClick={() => super.changeState("signUp")}>
            <Text style={styles.signupText}>Sign up</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
```

do the following:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => super.changeState("signUp")}>
            <Text style={styles.signupText}>Sign up</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
```